# Can searching on a phone for a tag with multiple words be improved?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, tag-search

Especially on phones it would be very helpful if spaces were converted to dashes when inside square brackets (that is, `[tag with dashes]` -> [tag-with-dashes](/questions/tagged/tag-with-dashes)). Right now searching on a phone for a tag with multiple words is a hassle because most of the keyboards take several clicks to get to a dash and square brackets. It would make using voice easier too. I've tagged this as android but if there isn't conflicting functionality then it would be nice if it was a global rule.

Or is there a reason that replacing spaces in square brackets would cause a problem?
Maybe functionality similar to what we see when tagging question could be used if the space replacement can't be done?

**edit**
We'd also need to convert `[tag - with - dashes]` -> [tag-with-dashes](/questions/tagged/tag-with-dashes) because the autocomplete (android S4) wants to add the spaces in when you type without them.

Comment: It took me a few seconds to work out what you meant. Then I understood, and I *liked* it. I've edited to add an example of what I think you mean; feel free to rollback if I got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks that does make the question better.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fantastic suggestion and is in the app as of version 1.0.30 coming out later this week.

However, I don't quite understand your edit. If the app is automatically converting every space it sees inside of tag markers to dashes, there isn't a need to use the autocomplete then enter a dash manually. Mind writing down steps for what you do to make it result in `[tag - with - dashes]`?

Comment: Yah you might be right. I'll test out the problem I thought I would run into when the new version is out and get back to you if I can break it. It may be that the problem won't come up with the replace functionality in place. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Can the same thing be done with the full version so that the behavior is consistent... or should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @BethWhitezel Separate question please :)

Comment: done... http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227447/152535

Comment: This works great. It doesn't have the spaces problem I was anticipating because you implemented the replacement as you type instead of just on leave.