# For tag searches can we replace spaces with dashes?

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

See [Can searching on a phone for a tag with multiple words be improved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226464/152535) for the similar, now implemented, functionality for mobile applications. It would be nice to replace all spaces with dashes within the square brackets for searching via tags. For example `[this search]` would automatically become [this-search](/questions/tagged/this-search). This would make it consistent with the behavior on the mobile app version 1.0.30 and it doesn't seem to conflict with any current behavior. It might also help "train" new users who might not know that all tags have dashes instead of spaces.